# Talking about front end web development frameworks from a designer's perspective

Tags: website-design, javascript

I am a web developer working at a company where the front end framework we have selected is Angular JS. I am now in the position where I am the 'resident expert' whatever that means. I have been tasked with teaching/explaining everything that our designers need to know about Angular JS. Therefore I have the following question:

What, if anything would a designer need to know about a front end JavaScript framework in general/Angular JS in particular in order to streamline their productivity? What kind of things are irrelevant? What kind of things are important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How you receive content from designers will control what is and is not relevant.**

If you receive merely **static images** for layout which you must then translate to HTML/CSS/JS there's nothing you need to explain to the designers. If you control all the markup and designers aren't creating markup, nothing changes *for them*. **The only possible caveat is if you intend to implement some dynamic content such as sliders or special DOM animations (parallax). You may need to explain the possibilities so that designers can work on various "states" of DOM animations**

If you receive HTML/CSS markup from the designers then you need to cover **all Angular JS HTML requirements**. After all if the markup is changing, they should be aware of new markup structures.

For example:

[image: angular js]

None of those highlighted attributes are standard front-end. Designers will need to learn them. In addition the double curly brace callouts **{{ }}** will need to be explained. Basically every single HTML element which is required for Angular JS should be explained.

Or, you could simply take control of the migration and edit everything for Angular JS needs. It really depends upon how designs are fleshed out, how much you trust the designers' work, and how much work you want to control.

Comment: at present I receive static images for layout/widgets which I then translate into JS/CSS/HTML. So I guess the short answer is the design team doesn't need anything.

Thank you for your well thought out response.

Comment: @AbrahamP Happy to help. I did add a bit to the static image paragraph.

Comment: To be that pedantic jerk--the highlighted elements are attributes, not tags.

Answer (score 2):

It would really depend on the particular framework. AFAIK, Angular.js isn't really a UI framework in that it's up to you to design the actual user interactions and UI visuals.

In general, though, you'd likely want your designers to:

- understand any page layout grid structures the framework provides.
- understand any built in UI components. Specifically

  - how the interactions work
  - What configuration options are available
  - what 'skinning' options are available
- understand how willing the FED's will be in terms of customizing any of the above to meet the requests of the designers.